# Add to cart link for product that sends user directly to checkout?

Tags: 6, ubercart

I'm working on a Drupal 6 site with Ubercart 2.9. I need to create a link for a single product that adds that product to the cart and proceeds directly to the checkout page. The link would be in an email blast, and by clicking it the user would completely skip the product's node/page, would skip the Cart page, and would be deposited directly onto the Checkout page where they can enter their payment/shipping info and proceed.

Possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Ubercart Cart Links Builder](http://drupal.org/project/uc_cartlinksbuilder) turned out to provide the exact functionality I needed.